# org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: wildfly-10

When i try to upload a deployment to wildlfy 10 i get this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
```

I have tried many suggested solutions but none of them had worked for me.
[tried modifying the Manifest file](http://canjur.blogspot.mx/2012/07/jboss-7-caused-by-orgdom4jdocumentexcep.html), [this question solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533847/wildfly-10-java-lang-classcastexception-org-dom4j-documentfactory-cannot-be-ca), but still with the same problem, i hope someone helps me to figure out what's wrong with this issue.

This is what i had  originally in all my files

jboss-deployment-structure-xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
        </exclude-subsystems> 
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

in the pom.xml:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including a dom4j library in your deployment. You need to determine where that is coming from and ensure it's excluded.

Comment: I just tried to upload a war file without the dom4j.jar still getting the same error. =/

Comment: The error is definitely that two versions of dom4j are being provided. Are you using a custom module or anything like that?

Comment: No i don't have any custom modules

Comment: Added  to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`  `<deployment>
  <exclusions>
   <module name="org.dom4j" />
  </exclusions>
 </deployment>´ oddly enough this didn't work the first time i tried this...

Comment: Nevermind this p.o.s is showing up the message again

Comment: You'll have to check your deployment for the dom4j library. If it's definitely not there you might need to inspect your dependencies to see if any of them shade in `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to contribute with another solution, because I also got that exception. I used wildfly(10.1.0), hibernate(4.0.1.Final) and poi(3.10-FINAL). To work fine, i just upgrade poi version to 3.16.