# Error while deploying gradle war file in wildfly 10

Tags: gradle, wildfly

Trying to deploying a war file of gradle.deploying is failing with error

`org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory  .`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wildfly 10: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533847/wildfly-10-java-lang-classcastexception-org-dom4j-documentfactory-cannot-be-ca)

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins  In my build.gradle there is nothing like dom4j.it is only present in the generated war file

Comment: I think you have to remove the transitive dependency on dom4j in your gradle build. It shouldn't end in your war file