# How to correctly set up pom with Hibernate Spatial and Widfly 10's JPA implementation?

Tags: hibernate, maven, wildfly-10

I had a maven project deployed on WildFly 10.1.0. When I tried to use Hibernate on it, I added its dependency on maven and I stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533847/wildfly-10-java-lang-classcastexception-org-dom4j-documentfactory-cannot-be-ca). To solve my problem, I used scope `provided` to make maven look for WildFly's jars instead of downloading on its own as below:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But now I want to use Hibernate Spatial within this project. I think standard WildFly `javaee-api` doesn't contain Hibernate Spatial. Keeping in mind I want to keep Hibernate from `javaee-api` how can I add Hibernate Spatial on my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered [this blog](https://www.volpe.com.py/hibernate/2016/06/17/wildfly-10-hibernate-spatial.html) and with this accomplished what I wanted. The only difference is that my postgres module was added on

```
<module name="com.postgresql"/>
```

and not on

```
<module name="org.postgresql"/>
```

Here's my pom spatial's dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.10.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```